# Spring MVC Boolean not binding to checkbox

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, binding, checkbox, boolean

Asking and then answering my own question for posterity's sake. I used a tag like this on my page:

```
<form:checkbox path="Active" label="label" />
```

This checkbox would correctly be checked (or unchecked) based on the boolean value pulled from the database. However, changes to the checkbox were never being bound to the entity and persisted back to the database. It turns out the problem was due to how my entity was constructed. My entity had a property and methods like this:

```
private Boolean Active;

public Boolean getActive() { 
    return this.Active;
}

public Boolean setActive(Boolean active) {
    this.Active = active;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    if (getActive() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return getActive().booleanValue();
}
```

It turns out that the "isActive()" method interferes with the value selected on the checkbox being bound back to the Active Boolean property on the entity. Renaming the method to anything else (e.g. "isPersonActive()" ) resolves the problem.

Comment: Don't use variable or property names starting with a caps in Java !!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your property name to `active` (small letters) in your object and jsp.

```
private Boolean active;

<form:checkbox path="active" label="label" />
```